# Get data out of map loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm new to mongodb. And running a query and iterating a loop on it and inside loop I'm fetching data from another query and inserting it into the first one. But when I log the first query data outside the map iteration it does't show the second query data there. Below is my code:-

```
banner=await Banner.find({teacher:{$nin:exclude_academy},status:1})
                .select('id position type type_id link banner amount')
                .sort({position:1})
banner.map(async(bann)=>{
    var course_data=await Course.findById(bann.type_id).exec();
    course_data['type']='course';
    bann['data']=course_data;
})
console.log(banner);
```

When I log the banner data it only shows first query data.
Below is my model structure:-

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const Schema=mongoose.Schema({
    teacher:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"User", required:true},
    position:{type:Number, default:0},
    type:{type:String, required:true},
    type_id:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    image:{type:String, required:true},
    amount:Number,
    data:Object,
    status:{type:Number, default:0},
    data:Object
},
{
    timestamps:true
});
module.exports=mongoose.model("Banner",Schema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved it and here is the answer to the question. I need to call the callback function to get the data. Below is the complete code:-

```
var banner=await Banner.find({teacher:{$nin:exclude_academy},status:1})
                        .select('id position type type_id link banner amount')
                        .sort({position:1})

    async function findData(type, type_id) {
            var course_data=await Course.findById(type_id).exec();
            course_data['type']='course';
            course_data['purchase_status']=status;
            return course_data;
    }

    await Promise.all(banner.map(async(bann)=>{
        if (bann.type_id!='')
        {
            const data = await findData(bann.type,bann.type_id);
            bann['data']=data;
        }
    }))
console.log(banner);
```